# помогите с наследованием python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, наследование

Как инициализировать родительский класс, передавая в подкласс атрибуты?

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, id, username):
        self.id = id
        self.username = username

    def create_game(self):
        pass
     
class G1(Game):
      def __init__(self, numbers_of_winners):
          super().__init__(self.id, self.username)
          self.numbers_of_winners = numbers_of_winners

class G2(Game):
      def __init__(self, numbers_of_winners):
          super().__init__(self.id, self.usernam)
          self.numbers_of_winners = numbers_of_winners

g1 = G1(4)
g2 = G2(3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте параметры родительского класса в подклассы.

```
class G1(Game):
      def __init__(self, id, username, numbers_of_winners):
          super().__init__(id, username)
          self.numbers_of_winners = numbers_of_winners
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Давайте по порядку:

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self, id, username):
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
```

Класс `Game` ждёт 2 аргумента для инициализации. `self.id` и `self.username` в экземпляре класса появляются **после** инициализации.

---

```py
class G1(Game):
      def __init__(self, numbers_of_winners):
          super().__init__(self.id, self.username)
          self.numbers_of_winners = numbers_of_winners
```

Класс-наследник `G1` для инициализации ждёт 1 аргумент. Затем он пытается вызвать инициализацию родителя со значениями `self.id` и `self.username`, которые появляются **после** того, как инициализирован класс `Game`. Т.е., на момент вызова `super().__init__` у экземпляра нет атрибутов `self.id` и `self.username`, которые Вы пытаетесь передать.

Аналогично с классом `G2`.

---

```py
g1 = G1(4)
g2 = G2(3)
```

Непонятно, что Вы тут хотели сделать. Класс `Game` (родитель) ожидает `id` и `username`, а в класс-потомок Вы передаёте какой-то один аргумент. Откуда тогда класс-родитель должен взять нужные ему `id` и `username`?

---

Один из путей решения: воспользоваться [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1192214/324059) @ioprst. Т.е. при инициализации наследников передавать им и `id`, и `username` и `numbers_of_winners`.